# SDL2 can't get mouse input when key is depressed

Tags: sdl-2

My SDL2 program ignores the mouse click if a key is depressed.  Here's my MCVE:

```
#include <SDL.h>

void myEventHandler(bool& mouseClicked, bool& letsQuit)
{
    SDL_Event event;

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:            letsQuit = true;   break;
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: mouseClicked = true;
        }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Init SDL
    SDL_Window*   sldWindow;
    SDL_Renderer* sdlRenderer;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
        return -1;
    if (!(sldWindow   = SDL_CreateWindow("", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
                                         SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,640, 480, 0))) 
        return -1;
    if (!(sdlRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(sldWindow, -1, 0))) 
        return -1;
    SDL_ClearError();

    //Initialize some conditions
    bool letsDrawRed= true;   //Draw a red square, not blue        
    bool letsQuit = false;    //Quit the program

    while (! letsQuit)
    {
        SDL_RenderPresent(sdlRenderer);

        //static int framesSinceLastMouseClick = 0; //latency
        bool       mouseClicked = false;
        myEventHandler (mouseClicked, letsQuit);

        if (letsDrawRed) SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(sdlRenderer, 255, 0, 0, 255); //draw square as red
        else             SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(sdlRenderer, 0, 0, 255, 255); //else draw it blue

        static SDL_Rect rect = { 0, 0, 100, 100 }; //draw the square
        SDL_RenderFillRect(sdlRenderer, &rect);

        //if clicked, and enough time since last click...
        //(All of these commented-out conditions fail too)
        //if (framesSinceLastMouseClick > 600 && mouseClicked) 
        //if (framesSinceLastMouseClick > 600 && SDL_GetMouseState(NULL, NULL))
        //if (mouseClicked)
        if (SDL_GetMouseState(NULL,NULL))
        {
            //framesSinceLastMouseClick = 0;  
            letsDrawRed = !letsDrawRed;
        }
        //else ++framesSinceLastMouseClick;
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(sldWindow); 
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

I left some things in comments to show they aren't the problem.  One is the latency condition (`framesSinceLastMouseClick`). The other is getting the mouse event from `SDL_PollEvent` rather than calling `SDL_GetMouseState`.)

Another thing to note is *this is only a problem when the key depressed is printable.* CapsLock, Shift, Alt, Ctrl, and Function keys don't cause a problem.

Platform is Visual Studio on MS Windows.

So...how can I get to that mouse while a key is depressed? That's going to be a problem in a real game!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out not to be SDL but the computer I'm on, which can't send info from the mouse (trackpad, actually) while a printable character is being pressed.  Apparently sending multiple signals from the keyboard is a longstanding problem, and "keyboard ghosting" (some keys -- in my case, trackpad clicks -- being lost) is a result.

At time of posting, I was able to check what output my keyboard/trackpad can send at https://keyboardtester.co/mouse-click-tester.html.